# Como saber qual é o o primeiro e último elemento com Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Boa noite pessoal. Estou com uma dúvida. Eu estou fazendo uma galeria de imagens e gostaria de saber como faço saber qual é o primeiro e último elemento. Tipo tenho as setas da direita e esquerda para imagem anterior ou próxima imagem. Dai tipo quando chegar na ultima imagem eu quero ocultar a seta para a próxima imagem e quando eu tiver na primeira imagem eu gostaria de ocultar a seta para a imagem anterior. Vocês podem me ajudar?

Comment: Você pode [incluir o código relevante](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/63234/edit) da sua galeria? Geralmente para fazer isso você guarda o número do item atual numa variável que é incrementada quando você avança, e decrementada quando retrocede. Sabendo quantos itens tem na galeria fica fácil saber se você está no primeiro ou no último.

Comment: @bfavaretto na verdade eu já faço isso que você falou. Na verdade eu só queria saber qual é o primeiro e o ultimo elemento

Comment: Bom, se você já tem essa variável, basta verificar se o valor dela é zero (ou 1, dependendo de como você implementou) para esconder a seta para esquerda, e comparar com o tamanho da coleção para esconder a seta para a direita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar os métodos `last` e `first`

```
$(".elemento").first(); // primeiro elemento
$(".elemento").last(); // último elemento
```